# Overhang subviews getting created twice Exception MAC

Tags: macos, nstabview, nsclipview

I am getting this exception in MAC where I am creating two Tab View Item in a Window.I have a table view for each tab.
I searched a lot but could not see any soultions? Can anybody help me ?

```
SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1265.21/AppKit.subproj/NSClipView.m:945
2014-07-30 13:54:08.204 Intralinks VIA[728:1003] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-07-30 13:54:08.204 Intralinks VIA[728:1003] Overhang subviews getting created twice!
2014-07-30 13:54:08.205 Intralinks VIA[728:1003] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9474025c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d321e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94740038 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8a088d41 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff92b34cfd -[NSClipView _addOverhangSubviewsIfNeeded] + 150
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9278c451 -[NSClipView setDocumentView:] + 530
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff9278bfe8 -[NSScrollView setDocumentView:] + 114
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9271e7de -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 358
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff927135ce loadNib + 327
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff92712b6c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff929a74d2 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 140
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff929a72ca -[NSWindowController loadWindow] + 196
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff929abf88 -[NSWindowController window] + 80
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff929ad0f0 -[NSWindowController showWindow:] + 36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.
The issue was I was calling showWindow from a Background Thread and not the main thread.